# Criteria builder group by and having count does not work

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

This is the query i want to achieve:

```
 SELECT *
FROM ROOMENTITY R
JOIN CALENDARENTITY C ON R.id = C.room_id
WHERE C.available = TRUE AND
      C.date BETWEEN :checkin AND
      :checkout
GROUP BY C.room_id
HAVING COUNT(C.room_id)>= diffdays
```

This is my code:

```
manager = factory.createEntityManager();
boolean hasPredicates = false;
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();

final CriteriaQuery<RoomEntity> q = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(RoomEntity.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

Root<RoomEntity> fromRooms = q.from(RoomEntity.class);
String checkinDate = filter.getCheckinDate();
String checkoutDate = filter.getCheckoutDate();
if (checkinDate != null || checkoutDate != null) {
    hasPredicates = true;
    java.sql.Date checkin = java.sql.Date.valueOf(filter.getCheckinDate());
    java.sql.Date checkout = ava.sql.Date.valueOf(filter.getCheckoutDate());
    int diffInDays = (int)( (checkout.getTime() - checkin.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) ) + 1;
    System.out.println("Days: " + diffInDays);
    Join<RoomEntity, CalendarEntity> calendarEntityJoin= fromRooms.join("calendarEntities", JoinType.INNER);
    calendarEntityJoin.on(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(calendarEntityJoin.join("calendarId").<Integer>get("room_id"),  fromRooms.<Integer>get("id"))
                );
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(calendarEntityJoin.<String>get("available"), true),
                        criteriaBuilder.between(calendarEntityJoin.join("calendarId").<Date>get("date"),
                                checkin, checkout)
                ));
    q.groupBy(calendarEntityJoin);
    q.having(criteriaBuilder.gt(criteriaBuilder.count(fromRooms), diffInDays));
}
```

My Room Entity:

```
public class RoomEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roomEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<CalendarEntity> calendarEntities;
}
```

My CalendarEntity:

```
public class CalendarEntity {

@EmbeddedId
private CalendarId calendarId;

@Basic
@Column(name = "available", nullable = false)
private Boolean available;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "room_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private RoomEntity roomEntity;
}
```

My CalendarEntity Embedded id:

```
@Embeddable
public class CalendarId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name= "date", nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "room_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer room_id;
}
```

Everything is good up until group by and having count. When i run this  and i print the query with this code below, then there is groupby/having:

```
if (hasPredicates)
            q.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
final TypedQuery<RoomEntity> TQ = manager.createQuery(q);
TQ.setFirstResult(filter.getStart());
TQ.setMaxResults(filter.getSize());
System.out.println("\n\nQuery:\n" + +Q.unwrap(JpaQuery.class).getDatabaseQuery().getSQLString() + "\n\n\n");
```

The query in the end is not what i want and it does implement group by and having count.

UPDATE:
This is the query i am getting right now:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.bathrooms, t1.bedrooms, t1.beds, t1.description, t1.exta_person_price, t1.house_rules, t1.max_people, t1.min_overnights, t1.neightborhood, t1.overnight_price, t1.square_meters, t1.title, t1.transport, t1.room_host, t1.room_location, t1.room_type_id FROM CALENDARENTITY t0, ROOMENTITY t1 WHERE (((t0.available = ?) AND (t0.date BETWEEN ? AND ?)) AND ((t0.room_id = t1.id) AND (t0.room_id = t1.id))) ORDER BY t1.overnight_price ASC
```

It is missing group by and having count!

Comment: Add some information about your expected result or errors which you are getting.

Comment: What i am expecting is the top query to be created, but in the end what is getting created is the top query with the 2 last lines, group by and having count.

Comment: Did you check if you have created the entities properly, using proper annotations you need not write so much code. Also, verify the query you are trying to create, it can be easily modified to do the same job in a more cleaner way.

Comment: The query i am trying to get in the end, already works if i run it as it is, but i cannot build it correctly with criteria builder. Group by and having count do not work and i dont know why.

Comment: Share code for RoomEntity and CalendarEntity @peterthunder .

Comment: I typed the basics of my 2 entities.

Comment: `<snide-remark>` Another case where 3rd party software gets in the way of writing a query, rather than helping? `</snide-remark>`  In this case it sounds like the SQL was easier to learn than the Builder package.

Comment: Why not just manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT ... ",RoomEntity.class)

Comment: The query worked after i used multiselect. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query worked after i used multiselect.

```
    Q.multiselect(fromRooms);
```